# How to round correctly SQL money type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, currency

I need help from SQL experts.  I'm trying to get data with 4 decimal places.  I'm doing some calculation on type "money".   However, the calculation doesn't round to mine liking.

Below is an example with regular numbers and the same values of money type.

```
DECLARE @MaxAmt money
DECLARE @MinAmt money

SET @MaxAmt = 207998693.55
SET @MinAmt = 20799442.35

SELECT
((207998693.55 - 20799442.35) / 2 + 20799442.35) / 24 AS Col1,
((@MaxAmt - @MinAmt) / 2 + @MinAmt) / 24 AS Col2
```

Col1 displays value equals to 4766627.831250000
While Col2 has value 4766627.8312.

My goal is to display only 4 decimal digits but it should be round correctly.  I would expect 4766627.8313 value.

Which would displayed after following casting.

```
SELECT CAST(((207998693.55 - 20799442.35) / 2 + 20799442.35) / 24 AS DECIMAL(12,4))
```

But when I deal with money type my value after a decimal is .8312 instead of .8313

Comment: That's because your `MONEY` calculation is probably using [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) - I'm assuming there's a system setting for this; what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL.  What can I do to have the rounding I need?

Comment: ... A quick look through the documentation isn't revealing anything;  I suspect that you may have to cast the columns to `DECIMAL` first: it's most likely being rounded off during the actual evaluation, so you're going to have to tell it what (larger) types you want ahead of time.

Comment: You are right as soon as I cast the first money variable it rounds as I expect.  Thanks for the help.  Put it in answer section, so I can except it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this behavior is that the `Money` type is using what's known as [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (a review of that page should reveal the likely reasons this was chosen).

Skimming through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be anything 'built in' to change this - you'll likely need to cast to `DECIMAL` first, explicitly, if you want to perform this in SQL itself.  (Alternatives include pulling at least some of the calculation out to your application layer, if necessary, or writing a stored procedure).